# Fluent NHibernate PersistentSpecification Test fails

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I currently have these Maps

```
public class CountryMap : ClassMap<Country>
{
    public CountryMap()
    {
        Table("tblCountry");
        Id(x => x.Id, "intCountryId");
        Map(x => x.Name, "strCountryName");
        HasMany(x => x.FlagImages)
            .Table("tblImage")
            .KeyColumn("intRelId")
            .Where("intObjId=29")
            .Not.Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class ImageMap : ClassMap<Image>
{
    public ImageMap()
    {
        Table("tblImage");
        Id(x => x.Id, "intImgId");
        Map(x => x.ObjId, "intObjId");
        Map(x => x.RelId, "intRelId");
        Map(x => x.ImageName, "strImage");
    }
}
```

and the following persistent specification test:

```
        PersistenceSpecification<Image>(session)()
            .CheckProperty(r => r.Id, 1)
            .CheckProperty(r => r.ImageName, "ss")
            .CheckProperty(r => r.ObjId, (int)ObjectType.Country)
            .CheckProperty(r => r.RelId, 102)
            .VerifyTheMappings();
```

Somewhat the test of `Image` failed.

The failure message is 
`Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<(null)>. Actual:<NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert: [HansaCrew.Models.Images.Image][SQL: INSERT INTO tblImage (intObjId, intRelId, strImage) VALUES (?, ?, ?); select last_insert_rowid()] ---> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: constraint failed
foreign key constraint failed`

I've checked it for 2 days and haven't find the reason. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it.

The problem of this piece of code lies here

```
        HasMany(x => x.FlagImages)
        .Table("tblImage")
        .KeyColumn("intRelId")
        .Where("intObjId=29")
        .Not.Cascade.All();
```

NHibernate automatically creates a foreign key constraint with tblImage, which has a lot of `intRelId`s which is not in the column of `intCountryId` in the table `tblCountry`. That's why the test fails saying foreign key constraint failure.

The way to solve this problem is to create a `view` in the database and then map the `view` into the `Image` model